# MySQL won't start because it can't find mysql-bin.000006 (Errcode 2), how do I fix this?

Tags: mysql, osx-mountain-lion, ampps

MySQL (part of [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com)) suddenly stopped working. Looking at `mysql.err` it says it can't start because it cannot find `mysql-bin.000006` (error 2).

Here is the full log from mysql.err:

```
130401 17:00:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130401 17:00:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130401 17:00:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130401 17:00:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130401 17:00:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130401 17:00:47 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130401 17:00:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130401 17:00:50 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 193114266
/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysqld: File './mysql-bin.000006' not found (Errcode: 2)
130401 17:00:50 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file './mysql-bin.000006', errno 2)
130401 17:00:50 [ERROR] Could not open log file
130401 17:00:50 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
130401 17:00:50 [ERROR] Aborting

130401 17:00:50  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130401 17:00:50  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 193114266
130401 17:00:50 [Note] /Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Here is the directory where all the binary log files live:

```
drwx------  128 cyberskull  admin      4352 Mar 31 02:46 redacted
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin   5242880 Apr  1 17:00 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin   5242880 Mar 31 02:46 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin  44040192 Apr  1 17:00 ibdata1
drwxr-xr-x@  74 cyberskull  admin      2516 Jan 30 22:31 mysql
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin   2053929 Mar 18 23:18 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin  44002874 Mar 23 19:40 mysql-bin.000002
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin  25182139 Mar 25 20:59 mysql-bin.000003
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin  21533910 Mar 28 19:51 mysql-bin.000004
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin  32820396 Mar 29 18:45 mysql-bin.000005
-rw-rw----    1 cyberskull  admin       114 Mar 30 14:33 mysql-bin.index
-rw-rw----@   1 cyberskull  admin    114303 Apr  1 17:00 mysql.err
drwxr-xr-x@  20 cyberskull  admin       680 Jan 30 22:31 performance_schema
drwxr-xr-x@   2 cyberskull  admin        68 Jan 30 22:31 test
```

What do I have to do to get MySQL up and running again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### OPTION #1

Just move the binary logs aside and start mysql

```
mv mysql-bin.* ..
```

Then, startup mysql

### OPTION #2

Edit the file `mysql-bin.index` and remove the line that has `mysql-bin.0000006`

Then, startup mysql

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Removing the last line from the log file seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I wasted 3 hours trying to solve this problem!!

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

1. Rename mysql-bin.index to mysql-bin.old. This way it can't find the file, but you still have it if you need it.
2. Enter the following command:

   ```
   cp mysql-bin.000002 mysql-bin.000006
   ```

   Optionally after that you can change the date and time to whatever you want when running this command:

   ```
   PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2013-03-14 10:00:00';
   ```